# Put a select in a variable

Tags: php

I would like to add a select with information from the database and save it in a variable. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me, it just shows me one record and not all records.

> 

```php
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM recaudacionBancaria")
foreach ($sql as $key => $value) {
    // class='theClass' value='".$value['cuenta']."'idCuenta='".$value['id']."'></div>";
    $cuenta = "<div class='btn-group'><select  class='form-control input-xs cue' name='cue' id='cue'>
                <option>'".$value['cuenta']."'</option>
                $cat= $conn->query("SELECT * FROM bancos");

                foreach ($cat as $key => $val) {
                    '<option value="'.$val["cuenta"].'">'.$val["cuenta"].'</option>';
                }
                </select></div>";
    echo '<tr>
    <td>'.$value['subsistema'].'</td>
    <td>'.$cajas.'</td>
    </tr>';
```

Comment: have you check print `$cat` is having all values or not ? and what is first `forloop`. `foreach ($sql as $key => $value) {`

Comment: Where is fetch result function who fetch record ? `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {` this line is missing. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: Yes, the query is ok, what is not ok is that the select only shows me a result when it should show 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Replace your code with this.

```php
$cat= $conn->query("SELECT * FROM bancos");
while($row = $cat->fetch_assoc()) {
 '<option value="'.$row["cuenta"].'">'.$row["cuenta"].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: There is no solution to the problem.